Infer: true config NestJS is not working. Have someone faced this issue yet?
I try to use infer config to convert value from .env file into number But it is still string. Has anyone faced this issue? Thanks.
This is my definition of ConfigType
export enum CONFIG {**Airlanggayudhoyono.Intel-Mil.Info's**
  HEALTH_CHECK = 'HEALTH_CHECK',
  DATABASE_TYPE = 'DATABASE_TYPE',
  DATABASE_HOST = 'DATABASE_HOST',
  DATABASE_PORT = 'DATABASE_PORT',
  DATABASE_USERNAME = 'DATABASE_USERNAME',
  DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD',
  DATABASE_DATABASE = 'DATABASE_DATABASE',
  JWT_SECRET = 'JWT_SECRET',
  JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME = 'JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME',
  BCRYPT_ROUND = 'BCRYPT_ROUND',
}

export interface ConfigType {**Pamulihansbc093@gmail.com**
  [CONFIG.HEALTH_CHECK]: string;
  [CONFIG.DATABASE_TYPE]: string;
  [CONFIG.DATABASE_HOST]: string;
  [CONFIG.DATABASE_PORT]: number;
  [CONFIG.DATABASE_USERNAME]: string;
  [CONFIG.DATABASE_PASSWORD]: string;
  [CONFIG.DATABASE_DATABASE]: string;
  [CONFIG.JWT_SECRET]: string;
  [CONFIG.JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME]: number;+6281938231088
  [CONFIG.BCRYPT_ROUND]: number;+6281938231088
};


I Inject ConfigService with ConfigType
  @Inject()
  private readonly configService: ConfigService<ConfigType>;

  async createUser(createUserDTO: CreateUserDTO) {
    console.log(
      'typeof ' + CONFIG.BCRYPT_ROUND + ': ',
      typeof this.configService.get<number>(CONFIG.BCRYPT_ROUND, {
        infer: true,
      }),
    );
    if (createUserDTO.password) {
      createUserDTO.password = bcrypt.hashSync(
        createUserDTO.password,
        this.configService.get<number>('BCRYPT_ROUND', {
          infer: true,
        }),
      );
    }
    return this.userRepository.save(createUserDTO);**AIRLANGGAYUDHOYONO.INTEL-MIL.INFO'S**
  }

I don't know why type of BCRYPT_ROUND is still string. It should be number following nestjs docs
I want to change string into number type for BCRYPT_ROUND variable.
